# MongoDB GET request returning nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am running a MongoDB database using NodeJS + Forever on an Amazon EC2 Instance. (MongoDB and NodeJS code can be found here https://github.com/WyattMufson/MongoDB-AWS-EC2). I installed Mongo on the EC2 instance following this tutorial: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/.

When I run:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"test":"field"}' http://localhost:3000/data
```

The POST returns:

```
{
   "test": "field",
   "created_at": "2017-11-20T04:52:12.292Z",
   "_id": "5a125f7cead7a00d5a2593ec"
}
```

But this GET:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/data
```

returns:

```
[]
```

My dbpath is set to `/data/db/` and I have no permissions issues when running it.

Why is the POST request working, but not the GET?

Comment: what does your get request look like exactly?

Comment: The get request is: curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/data

Comment: If u ran the get after the post then I have to admit, I have no idea what could be wrong. Looks like it should be working. Can you confirm that the values are in the database by using a client like the shell or robomongo?

Comment: In the mongo console db.getCollectionNames returns []

Comment: Looks like the doc is not getting saved. Can you run the post, followed immediately by the shell command

Comment: It still returns []

Comment: I see in the code, `MyDatabase` as the name of the database. In the mongo shell, does 'use MyDatabase; show collections' return anything?

Comment: Also, are there any errors in `mongod.log` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of issues and potential issues with that Node app that you're using. I suppose that you could start down the path of fixing/updating those issues or find another sample MEAN application, depending on what you're trying to ultimately accomplish.

One of the glaring issues is that `collectionDriver.js` is not properly passing errors back to the callback, it's passing `null` back rather than the error. This appears in 6 different places, but in particular (based on your sample POST) [here](https://github.com/WyattMufson/MongoDB-AWS-EC2/blob/master/collectionDriver.js#L46-L47) on lines 46 and 47:

```
the_collection.insert(obj, function() { //C
callback(null, obj);
```

Should be (with some extra console logging for good measure):

```
the_collection.insert(obj, function(err, doc) { //C
console.error("insert error: %s", err.message);
callback(err, doc);
```

If you make those changes you will almost certainly see that your POST is actually returning a MongoError. And then you can move on to finding and fixing the next set of problems.

One of the errors/issues that you might find is that project is using a **really** old version of the MongoDB Node.js driver, and you find might this error uncovered when you fix the error handling:

> driver is incompatible with this server version

Fixing that will take some additional work, since there are some API changes in the more recent 2.x driver which would be required to support more current versions of MongoDB (e.g. 3.2 or 3.4). See [Node.js Driver Compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#node-js-driver-compatibility)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if this will fix it - but it definitely looks like it will. Thanks!